# Drawing boxes of any size and any location

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

How can I draw rectangles of any size and any placement on the current page?

```
    \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} 
    \documentclass[landscape]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepgflibrary{decorations.shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, decorations.shapes,decorations.markings, shapes, fit, arrows, positioning, trees, mindmap, calc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

    \draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] (current page.center) rectangle (3cm);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand your question, so I have to make an informed guess. Here is an example in which multiple circles and boxes are drawn, relative to the actual size of the page, as you have it right now:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} 
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, decorations.shapes,decorations.markings, shapes, fit, arrows, positioning, trees, mindmap, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

\draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] (current page.center) circle (3cm);

\draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.25] ($(current page.center)+(3,0)$) circle (3cm);

\draw [line width=1mm,opacity=.5] ($(current page.center)+(5,1)$) rectangle ($(current page.center)+(7,3)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The example uses TikZ coordinate calculations to use positioning relative to the page center. Is this what you want? If not, please clarify. Since you are using "remember picture", don't forget to compile twice!

Comment: I'm trying to draw random boxes all over the paper basically. Varying sizes and varying locations. I had `circle` in the code because `rectangle` in place of `circle` wouldn't run, and I didn't know what I had to change.

Answer (score 6):

With PSTricks.

### *Ellipses and Rectangles:*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\SpecialCoor

\makeatletter
\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\textwidth/10,
    yunit=\dimexpr\textheight/10,
    linewidth=2pt,
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](10,10)
\psLoop{20}
{
    \psframe[linecolor=red](!rand 801 mod 100 div rand 801 mod 100 div)(!rand 801 mod 100 div 2 add rand 801 mod 100 div 2 add)
    \psellipse[linecolor=orange](!rand 601 mod 100 div 2 add rand 601 mod 100 div 2 add)(!rand 1001 mod 500 div rand 1001 mod 500 div)
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### *Circles and Rectangles:*

[image]

```
% A4 paper size 21.0cm × 29.7cm
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2cm]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\makeatletter
\psset
{
    linewidth=2pt,
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](17.0,25.7)
\psLoop{10}
{
    \psframe[linecolor=red](!rand 1501 mod 100 div rand 2371 mod 100 div)(!rand 1501 mod 100 div 2 add rand 2371 mod 100 div 2 add)
    \pscircle[linecolor=orange](!2 rand 1301 mod 100 div add 2 rand 2171 mod 100 div add){!rand 1001 mod 500 div}
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### *About `rand`*

Let's consider `rand 501 mod 100 div` that produces a real number between 0.00 and 5.00 inclusive.

[image]

Comment: @Karlsstudents Oh, I thought it would be like one line. It's fine then. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to remove `\makeatletter`.